# Responsive CSS with flex-box is driving me nuts

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

I've got an `image-text-image` sandwich I try to make responsive. It looks like I almost made it, except for the Media Query and text width part. Could someone take a look to see what I'm doing wrong.

[Here's the link for the codepen](http://codepen.io/Adrenaline22/pen/LkKkaV)

Comment: do you want them to be displayed vertically on small screens?

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex-direction: column; in media queries. look at this screenshot http://jmp.sh/YpWavrl.
and then you can give width 100% to .first and .second also.